# java: define a return type in an interface that must implement another interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I am trying to make the following implementation of classes in my project and still have no clue how to define it:

```
 interface A{ ... }

 interface B{
 public List<A> fooFunction(); 
 }

 class C implements B{
 @Override
 public List<(another class which implements interface A)> fooFunction(){
 ...
 }
```

I get the error **incompatible error: anotherClass cannot be converted to A**
which I find logical, still how can I define this implementation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose I have `B x = new C(); x.fooFunction().add(new ImplementationOfA());` - how would you expect that to work?

Comment: @Alex you can see that generics are strictly typed, you cannot rely on polymorphism while playing with generics

Comment: Thanks everyone... So you are telling me that the whole thought of the implementation is wrong, right?